# How to remove empty documents from a Term-Document-Matrix in R

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus, term-document-matrix

So I created a term document matrix from a corpus in R:

`tdm_tfidf <-TermDocumentMatrix(corpus,control=list(weighting=weightTfIdf))`

However, there is a warning that the TDM contains empty documents:

`Warning: In weighting(x) :
 empty document(s): 54 80 130 142 151 156 162 203 215 248 264 280 284 300 326 327 355 389 486 558 637 668 680 812 872 986 1003 1121 1168 1306 1456 1546 1547 1551 1552 1574 1690 1841 1867 1874 1943 1998 2112 2113 2117 2452 2471 2514 2515 2632 2703 2837 2924 2947 2967 2968 3002 3023 3121 3149 3161 3258...`

Is there a way to remove empty documents from a TDM? I know that it is possible for a document term matrix!

`rowTotals <- apply(dtm_tfidf , 1, sum)
dtm_tfidf   <- dtm_tfidf[rowTotals> 0, ]`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `colTotals <- apply(tdm_tfidf , 2, sum)` and `tdm_tfidf <- , tdm_tfidf[ , rowTotals> 0]`

Comment: thank you very much it worked but you need to replace "rowTotals" with "colTotals" in the second one ;) Thank you very much!!!